# Code 4 and Code 7 errors in XNA

Tags: xna

I'm using XNA 4.0 and I did one app in XNA. The aim of the apps is read the content from an XML file. I successfully ran the application on my Windows machine, but when I deploy them to my Xbox I get  Code 4 and Code 7 errors.

What should I look at to diagnose and fix them?

Answer (score 2):

**Code 4** is "unhandled exception". You need to add a top-level exception handler to identify the source of the exception ([this blog post](http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2008/10/catching-exceptions-on-xbox-360/) may help). Or possibly turn on "break on all exceptions" in the debugger. Once you know the cause of the unhandled exception, fix it.

**Code 7**: "These are caused by logging out of the account with the App Hub Membership. This crash never occurs in non-review play." ([source](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/resources/help/peer_review_not_so_evil_checklist)). You can ignore it. You won't fail review for a code 7.